# Is there a simpler way to perform number to word conversion?

Tags: apex

Here's my code so far:

```
public with sharing class NumbersToWordsConversionClass {

    public string wordText{set;get;}

    public string convert() {
        try{
            wordText=convert(numberval);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.debug(e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long numberval { get; set; }


    public String[] units = new String[]{'Zero ','One ','Two ','Three ','Four ','Five ','Six ','Seven ','Eight ','Nine ','Ten ',

        'Eleven ','Twelve ','Thirteen ','Fourteen ','Fifteen ',
        'Sixteen ','Seventeen ','Eighteen ','Nineteen '
        };
        public String[] tens = new String[]{'','','Twenty ','Thirty ','Forty ','Fifty ','Sixty ','Seventy ','Eighty ','Ninety '};
        public String[] zero=new String[]{'NIL'};

        public  String convert(long i) {
            try{
                //
                if (i == 0) return zero[integer.valueOf(i)];
                if( i < 20)  return units[integer.valueOf(i)];
                if( i < 100) return tens[integer.valueOf(i)/10] +((math.mod(i , 10) > 0)? '' + convert(math.mod(i , 10)):'' );

                if( i < 1000) return units[integer.valueOf(i)/100] + ' Hundred ' + ((math.mod(i , 100) > 0)?' ' + convert(math.mod(i , 100)):'' );
                if( i < 10000) return units[integer.valueOf(i)/1000] + ' Thousand ' + ((math.mod(i , 1000) > 0)?' ' + convert(math.mod(i , 1000)):'' );

                if( i < 100000) return convert(i / 1000) + ' Thousand ' + ((math.mod(i , 1000) > 0)? '' + convert(math.mod(i ,1000)):'' ) ;
                if( i < 10000000) return convert(i / 100000) + ' Lakh ' + ((math.mod(i, 100000) > 0)? '' + convert(math.mod(i , 100000)):'' );

                if( i < 1000000000) return convert(i / 10000000) + 'Crore ' + ((math.mod(i, 10000000) > 0)? '' + convert(math.mod(i, 10000000)):'' );


            }
            catch(Exception e)

            {
                System.debug(e);
            }
            return convert(i / 1000000000) + ' Bilian ' + ((math.mod(i , 1000000000) > 0)? '' + convert(math.mod(i , 1000000000)):'' +'Only' ); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Or do you just want to know if someone has a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Using Lakh and Crore complicates your code. If you were to use thousands and millions, the code would be far easier, and in fact this question would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some recursion and lookup tables, we get code that's decently shorter and extensible in different ways. While I previously [wrote a different answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/158083/number-to-word-logic) to handle just lakh, this code can handle almost any base-10 style system, so you can alter it in different ways.

The core design is similar to your own, using recursion, but just taken to the next level. Since Integer is limited to just over 2 billion (twenty crore), there's no need to extend further than this, but you could also convert this to Long to use even larger words if you wanted to.

Here's the new version:

```
public class NumbersToWordsConversionClass {
    public string wordText { get; set; }
    public Integer numberVal { get; set; }
    // Action method to be called by button or link
    public void convert() {
        wordText = numberToEnglish(numberVal);
    }

    static String[] firstTwenty = new String[] { 'NIL','One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine',
            'Ten','Eleven','Twelve','Thirteen','Fourteen','Fifteen','Sixteen','Seventeen','Eighteen','Ninteen' };
    static String[] tens = new String[] { '','','Twenty','Thirty','Forty','Fifty','Sixty','Seventy','Eighty','Ninety' };
    static String[] powers = new String[] { 'Crore','Lakh','Thousand','Hundred' };
    static Integer[] thresholds = new Integer[] { 100000000, 100000, 1000, 100 };

    static String[] convert(Integer value) {
        String[] result = new String[0];
        Boolean less20 = value < 20, less100 = value < 100;
        if(less20) {
            result.add(firstTwenty[value]);
        } else if(less100) {
            Integer tenValue = value / 10, oneValue = Math.mod(value, 10);
            result.add(tens[tenValue]);
            if(oneValue > 0) {
                result.add(firstTwenty[oneValue]);
            }
        }
        if(less100) {
            return result;
        }
        if(value > 0) {
            for(Integer index = 0; index < thresholds.size(); index++) {
                if(thresholds[index] <= value) {
                    result.addAll(convert(value / thresholds[index]));
                    result.add(powers[index]);
                    value = Math.mod(value, thresholds[index]);
                }
            }
            if(value > 0) {
                result.addAll(convert(value));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static String numberToEnglish(Integer value) {
        return value != null && value >= 0? String.join(convert(value),' '): '';
    }
}
```